# Flash builder mobile app to integrate webcam

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flash-builder

I am new to mobile development. During exploration of various IDEs, I got to know that Flash Builder is the best IDE for developing mobile application. One good reason to choose FB is that it follows the principle 'Code once deploy anywhere (iOS, Android etc...)'

I am trying to build a sample mobile application where one person can see the other person's webcam. Both will log in to the same application. The agent person can share his/her webcam to the caller person. Would like to know whether FlashBuilder has support for webcam API. Would there be any standalone applications (on Adobe site or any where else) which provide instant webcam functionality.

And could someone suggest the tutorials needed to implement the above functionality.

Thanks
Sk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at the following, and get some ideas:

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/video-chat-with-livecycle-collaboration-services-lccs/

And look at this for some ideas on doing the code, and setting up a project:

http://www.realeyes.com/blog/2011/10/31/new-in-flash-player-11-encoding-live-video-to-h-264avc/

You will most likely need to connect to a video streaming server like Adobe's FMS or Red 5.

```
protected function publishCamera():void
{
ns_out = new NetStream(nc);
ns_out.attachCamera(cam);
var h264Settings:H264VideoStreamSettings = new H264VideoStreamSettings();
h264Settings.setProfileLevel(H264Profile.BASELINE, H264Level.LEVEL_3_1);

// ALTHOUGH FUTURE VERSIONS OF FLASH PLAYER SHOULD SUPPORT SETTING
// ENCODING PARAMETERS ON h264Settings BY
// USING THE setQuality() and setMode() METHODS,
// FOR NOW YOU MUST SET THE PARAMETERS ON THE CAMERA FOR:
// BANDWITH, QUALITY, HEIGHT, WIDTH, AND FRAMES PER SECOND.
// h264Settings.setQuality(30000, 90);
// h264Settings.setMode(320, 240, 30);

cam.setQuality(90000, 90);
cam.setMode(320, 240, 30, true);
cam.setKeyFrameInterval(15);
ns_out.videoStreamSettings = h264Settings;
trace(ns_out.videoStreamSettings.codec + “, ” + h264Settings.profile + “, ” + h264Settings.level);
ns_out.publish(“mp4:webCam.f4v”, “live”);

var metaData:Object = new Object();
metaData.codec = ns_out.videoStreamSettings.codec;
metaData.profile = h264Settings.profile;
metaData.level = h264Settings.level;
metaData.fps = cam.fps;
metaData.bandwith = cam.bandwidth;
metaData.height = cam.height;
metaData.width = cam.width;
metaData.keyFrameInterval = cam.keyFrameInterval;
metaData.copyright = “Realeyes Media, 2011″;
ns_out.send(“@setDataFrame”, “onMetaData”, metaData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shaun for the response. Let me go through the links and get back to you